# Failed to install 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 2.0.0'

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, nuget-package, serilog

I am trying to install Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer through Nuget. Using VS 2013 and .Net framework is 4.7.2. I checked dependencies before installing and it says it's compatible with framework 4.7.2. But i get below error and installation gets rollback.

"Could not install package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 2.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets
'.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework"
Am I missing something?

Comment: Why are you using such an old Visual Studio version? The problems may be caused by the old NuGet client it uses

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 2.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/2.0.0) targets only .NET Standard 2.0 (which indeed is compatible with .NET Framework 4.7.2).

However, support for the `netstandard` moniker for VS 2013 was only [introduced in NuGet v2.12](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/release-notes/nuget-2.12).

My guess is that you have an old version of the NuGet extension installed on your Visual Studio 2013. Make sure you update it to [VS 2013 VSIX v2.12.0](https://www.nuget.org/downloads).

Alternatively, you can use the [NuGet CLI tool](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) to install the package instead of Visual Studio.

---

ps: You should consider upgrading Visual Studio to 2019, if possible.

Comment: Will it work on VS 2015? I am not sure if I can upgrade to VS 2019

Comment: @abhiJ It will work with VS 2015 if you install the Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 (at least). For VS 2015 you'll need [NuGet 3.4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/release-notes/nuget-3.4) or later

Answer (score -1):

Update the Visual Studio 2013 to latest version and try